# Yii2 RESTful api

Tags: yii2, api

Здравствуйте!Скажите пожалуйста как в Yii2 RESTful api вывести значение по параметрам?К примеру /list?id=2

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!

Для реализации RESTful API в Yii2 есть [yii\rest\ActiveController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#extending-active-controller)

Пример:

```
class ListController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\List';
}
```

ListController автоматом генерирует стандартные методы для app\models\List

Обращение /list?id=2 - это actionIndex(), однако в данный момент он выводит список всех app\models\List, для просмотра по id используется /list/view?id=2

Если необходимо добиться именно такого роута, то можно удалить стандартные методы и реализовать их самостоятельно:

```
class ListController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\List';

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['index'];
        unset($actions['view'];
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        // some code
        // check $id and etc
        return $modelClass::findOne($id);
    }

}
```

P.S. Обратите внимания, что остальные методы (Update, Delete и т.д.) так же реализуются этим контроллером, стоит это учитывать

Comment: Супер спасибо вам большое!